# Redis Cluster - transaction vs LUA script, which one results in a better performance?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

If I can get the same result with both transaction and LUA script (not the cached script) in a Redis cluster, which one has the better performance? LUA script must be compiled everytime the it is executed, right? So does it affect to the performance?

I can't find any way to cache a script on servers of a Redis cluster and just receive only one sha1 for that script

And based on the document of Transaction:

> "we may deprecate and finally remove transactions"

Is there any reason why Transaction will be replaced by LUA script

Sorry if I get anything wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackExchange.Redis does the work behind the scenes to automatically use prepared scripts automatically (`SCRIPT LOAD`, `EVALSHA`, etc), so on a per-call basis there is very little script overhead. Additionally, transactions may involve a latency step to confirm assertions before deciding whether to complete or abort the script. It is also often maddeningly awkward to use redis transactions due to the neee to fetch required data first, issuing assertions, etc. This also has bandwidth and latency impact. For all these reasons: in general, scripts are usually more convenient. However, there are times when they might not apply. Additionally, scripting may not be enabled on your server (whether for versioning or security concerns). Note that if you get your script logic wrong, very bad things can happen (blocking the server without hope of recovery).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
StackExchange.Redis can cache a script on only one server by using LuaScript.Load(server), and it doesn't have any method to cache a script on all servers that a "ConnectionMultiplexer" handles, right?

Comment: @NhatHongLy it tracks separately which scripts have been loaded against which servers; redis cluster itself doesn't have a "load this everywhere" command. This is something that there is a feature request logged against the library though. It isn't particularly difficult - I'm also not sure it is particularly *necessary* either, though, since the library just makes it all work anyway. But I'll probably add it as soon as the core-clr stuff is merged.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SCRIPT LOAD` to get the sha1 for any script (or compute it outside Redis, for example, with `sha1sum` from the shell on your script but remember to handle newlines).

WRT to performance, while I have no formal data to support this claim, my experience suggests that the differences are negligible, if any.

> Is there any reason why Transaction will be replaced by LUA script

Lua is like doing a transaction on steroids, and `MULTI` offers nothing (besides the optimistic lock pattern) that Lua doesn't already provide. That said, I find it hard to believe it will be obsoleted entirely.

Comment: Since the OP mentions SE.Redis (tags), it is worth emphasising that the `SCRIPT LOAD` etc is handled automatically.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah, missed that tag... good to see you BTW, missed you at RDD and in general.

Comment: Alas, I had just come back from San Diego, and was about to head to Seattle - couldn't squeeze in another away-day.